# Creating playlist from sd card and sending it to Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast, playlist

I am developing an application to send playlist to Chromecast. 
I want to create playlist from local media (video, images). My application will get all the videos and images from specific folder and it will create a playlist. This playlist will be send to Chromecast.

How to achieve this, I have created NanoHTTPD server on my mobile. And serving video from there. But this server serves only one video at a time.

I want serve specific folder from my local server and then want to create playlist of all the videos and images stored in that folder.

This is my NanoHTTPD :-

```
  public class WebServer extends NanoHTTPD
```

{

```
public WebServer() throws IOException 
{
    super(8089);
}

@Override
public Response serve(String uri, Method method,
        Map<String, String> header, Map<String, String> parameters,
        Map<String, String> files)
{
    String answer = "";

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    String path;
    String fileOutput="";
    int counter;

    try 
    {
                    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Video/bbb.mp4";
                    fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new NanoHTTPD.Response(Status.OK, "video/mp4", fis);
}
}
```

This is how i am casting video :-

```
private void startVideo()
{
    MediaMetadata mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata( MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE );
    mediaMetadata.putString( MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, getString( R.string.video_title ) );

    String videoURL = Configuration.video_url; 

    MediaInfo mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder( videoURL )
    .setContentType( getString( R.string.content_type_mp4 ) )
    .setStreamType( MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED )
    .setMetadata( mediaMetadata )
    .build();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Video build " + videoURL, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    try 
    {
        mRemoteMediaPlayer.load( mApiClient, mediaInfo, true )
        .setResultCallback( new ResultCallback<RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult>() 
                {
            @Override
            public void onResult( RemoteMediaPlayer.MediaChannelResult mediaChannelResult )
            {
                if( mediaChannelResult.getStatus().isSuccess() ) 
                {
                    mVideoIsLoaded = true;
                    mButton.setText( getString( R.string.pause_video ) );

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Media loaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
                } );
    } 
    catch (IllegalStateException e) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem occurred with media during loading : " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem occurred with media during loading : " + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Please help me, I unable to understand what to do.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- Configure your local server to serve files by their name, i.e. if I want to get a file named "video1.mp4", I would need to use "http://.../video1.mp4". This allows having multiple files accessible when needed.
- You need to create a queue using the appropriate apis: create MediaQueueItems, one for each video in your playlist, and then put them in an array and load that using the RemoteMediaPlayer#queueLoad() method. You may want to set autoplay=true on them.

You can look at the [CastVidoes-android](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android) app for an example; the only difference would be that urls in your case for videos are pointing to your embedded server.

Comment: Thank you sir that really helped me a lot. Now the problem is I am sending video and images together as a playlist. It plays my video but when it has to load image it stucks there itself.

Comment: The Queueing APIs that have been added to the SDK is for Video and Audio items; there is currently no support for images in a queue. For example, a video/audio item in a queue plays and ends and then queue advances to the next item; if you have an image, there is no "duration" or "play" functionality associated with, so there is no notion of "advance to the next item".

Comment: Ok sir, But is there any way to achieve this. I mean, I want to make playlist of videos and images together. So can I achieve this by any way or there is no possibility to do this.

Comment: You can write your own custom receiver and handle both of those media types and send your own messages to your receiver.

Comment: Sir, how can I show cromecast device list dialog on button click instead of onCreateOptionsMenu. Cant you share some code?

Comment: You need to use MediaRouteButton (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/MediaRouteButton.html), take a look at this sample: https://github.com/googlecast/MediaRouter-Cast-Button-android

Comment: Thank you sir, I achieved to create playlist of images and videos without using custom receiver. I used styled receiver provided by google. I used multiple objects of MediaInfo. I am passing each MediaInfo to chromecast after the last media is loaded on the chromecast